# Сортировка Queryset по CharField в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, orm

Есть `Queryset` с полем `priority` и данными - '`high`' '`low`' '`medium`' , подскажите как отсортировать по возврастанию и убыванию, `order_by('priority')` фильтрует по алфавиту

Answer (score 0):

создайте отдельное поле для с индексом для сортировки

Comment: можно пример? сейчас я просто наполняю список через цикл с поочередностью  'high' 'medium' 'low' и для обратного результата использую reverse()

Comment: order_by('priority')  cортировка по возрастанию подразумевается по-умолчанию. YourModel.objects.order_by('-priority'). знак “минус” в "-priority" указывает на “нисходящую” сортировку.